# Wrong result of print in FUNC

Tags: c#, func

I have problem with this code, the code need to print this result:

```
56789 56789
```

But the result is:
99999 99999

why?

```
   class Program

    {

     static int m_k = 0;
    static Func<int>[] P=new Func<int>[5];

    static void F(int n,Func<int>[] T)
    {
        if (n>0)
        {

            P[m_k] = () => T[m_k]();
            m_k++;
            F(n-1,T);
        }
        else
        {
            P[m_k] = () => T[m_k]();
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Func<int>[] T = new Func<int>[5];
        Func<int>[] S = new Func<int>[5];
        T[0] = () => 5;
        T[1] = () => 6;
        T[2] = () => 7;
        T[3] = () => 8;
        T[4] = () => 9;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {

            S[i] = () => T[i]();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(S[i]());
        }
        F(4,T);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(P[i]());
        }
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tring to access to modified cluser!!!
In computer science, a closure is a first-class function with free variables that are bound in the lexical environment.

You can fix this code by this:

```
static void F(int n,Func<int>[] T)
{
      if (n>0)
      {
          int tmp=m_k
          P[m_k] = () => T[tmp]();
          m_k++;
          F(n-1,T);
      }
      else
      {
          P[m_k] = () => T[m_k]();
      }
}
```

and by this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    int j=i;
    S[i] = () => T[j]();
}
```